# OS X: move to different partition

Tags: macos, partitioning

I have 4 partitions on my Mac mini, one for OS X 10.6, one for OS X 10.5, one for OS X 10.7 and one data partition. I now want to move OS X 10.7 to the first partition (assuming it would be faster) instead of reinstalling it. Is this possible using Disk Utilities, e.g. by having booted to OS X 10.5.

Comment: The only reason that I can think of a different partition on the same disk being faster would be if it has more free space available for swap. Is this what you're going for?

Comment: You could do it with Carbon Copy Cloner, but you'd need a spare partition or external drive to use whilst shuffling. I don't think it's going to make any real practical difference though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Disk Utility to restore from another partition, but the better answer (which is what I do myself) is to use Carbon Copy Cloner, Backup what you want to move to an external disk (I use a USB3 multiple bare mechanism mounter but any USB external drive would do just as well), then use the backed up partition (on the USB drive) to boot, format your volume, and restore.

Usually takes me less than an hour soup to nuts, but I can't speak for compatibility under10.5 - personally I'd use 10.6 or 10.7, you may need to get an old version of CCC from bombich.com to run under 10.6 or 10.7, I don't know. CCC should be able to backup all partitions since it's essentially just a wrapper for rsync.

Hope this helps.